# Nginx - How to get user name after password authentication with auth_basic?

Tags: authentication, logging, nginx

I restricted access to my web server [using auth_basic method in Nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-password-authentication-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) but I would like to be able to programatically get the username of the authenticated user so I can create a log file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://nginx.org/r/$remote_user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the phpinfo() file, I figured that the logged user is set in:

```
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']
```